# Error while uploading image from my mobile devices?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

This is my models.py file

```html
class Report_item(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text='*Title for the post e.g. item identity')
    item_type = models.CharField(default="", max_length=100,
                                 help_text='*Enter the item name you found e.g. Marksheet,key,wallet')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=60, help_text='*Enter the address/street where you find this item')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60, help_text='*Enter the city name')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    Description = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True,help_text='*Enter full description about item')
    publish = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    image = models.ImageField(default="add Item image",
                             help_text='*Please uplocad a item image to identify by the owner')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + "      " + str(self.publish)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('feed:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-date"]
```

This is my upload views:

```html
class ReportCreate(generic.CreateView):
    model = Report_item
    fields = ['title', 'item_type', 'location', 'city', 'image', 'Description']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.owner = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return FormMixin.form_valid(self, form)
```

This is my view.py file

```html
def IndexView(request):
    query_list = Report_item.objects.filter(publish=True)
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        query_list = query_list.filter(Q(title__icontains=query) |
                                       Q(item_type__icontains=query) |
                                       Q(city__icontains=query) |
                                       Q(location__icontains=query) |
                                       Q(Description__icontains=query)).distinct()

    context = {
        "object_list": query_list
    }
    return render(request, "feed/index.html", context)
```

This is my feed/index file

```html
{% for obj in object_list %}
      <div class="thumbnail" onclick="window.open('{% url 'feed:detail' obj.id %}','mywindow');" style="cursor: pointer;">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-9">
                  <table class="mytable table-responsive">
                        <tr><td class="my-td-item">Title</td><td>{{ obj.title }}</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="my-td-item">Item Type</td><td>{{ obj.item_type }}</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class="my-td-item">Location</td><td>{{ obj.location }}</td></tr>
                      <tr><td class="my-td-item">City</td><td>{{ obj.city }}</td></td></tr>
                  </table>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-3">
                  <img class="img-responsive center" src="{{ obj.image.url }}" alt="backmyitem" width="80" height="100" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                  <br><b><p style="font-size: 10px;text-align:center;">Posted Date</b><br>{{ obj.date }}</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="more-detail-div col-md-12">
                  <a class="">More Detail</a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
```

When I upload an image from my laptop in my application, the image upload successfully and also images display in feed/index.html but at the same time when the same image I upload using my mobile phone or any other mobile devices then It causes the error. Even the image upload successfully but in the admin section as well as in the feed page image upload successfully and its name and path is also correct but is not display in admin as well as in the index file When I try to open the image in a new tab then it shows 403 forbidden.

The error in the ngin

```html
2018/08/20 19:34:37 [error] 4498#4498: *89 open() "/home/ubuntu/media/153476127499997915256.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 103.201.$
```

x-error log is following:

Comment: Where is your *upload view*?

Comment: Sorry, now I add in the question. Please help me.

Comment: Can you add the error traceback, error response, something like that?

Comment: The error in the nginx server is the following 2018/08/20 19:34:37 [error] 4498#4498: *89 open() "/home/ubuntu/media/153476127499997915256.jpg" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 103.201.$

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge Sir have you find any solution?

Comment: unfortunately, No :(

Comment: have you understood completely my problem? Your knowledge is a gem in Django. So I wish I got an answer from you after one day. It is very important for my society.

Comment: @imsaiful Could you please check the permissions on this file for me...you can do this by using `ls -l /home/ubuntu/media/153476127499997915256.jpg` in your terminal.

Comment: @imsaiful I don't think this problem is raising due to *Django*. I didn't have any experience with aws environment :(

Comment: @user9245558 I got this by running your command -rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 3095561 Aug 20 10:35 /home/ubuntu/media/153476127499997915256.jpg

Comment: Hello @JerinPeter please check this now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51955531/unexceptional-behaviour-of-my-django-application-image-hosting-on-aws